# How to get matches sequentially using perl

Tags: perl

i have +1000 json files like this :

```
({
  "Companies": [
    {
      "company": "COMPANY_1",
      "time": "20DAYS"
    },
    {
      "company": "COMPANY_2",
      "time": "1DAY"
    },
  ]
})
```

using perl how can i get like this output :

```
COMPANY_1:20DAYS,COMPANY_2:1DAY
```

im trying this command

```
perl -lnE '$x = (split /=/,$ARGV)[4], say "$x:", join ",", /(?<="company":")[^"]*/g,/(?<="time":")[^"]*/g' file.txt
```

but i get ouput like this :

```
COMPANY_1,COMPANY_2,1DAY,20DAYS
```

Desired output :

```
COMPANY_1:20DAYS,COMPANY_2:1DAY
```

Thanks

Comment: Two *my data is almost but not quite JSON* questions from two different people in a row? Weird. This one's not quite as easy to turn into actual JSON though.

Comment: That's not JSON. You can't have `(` `)` in a JSON file.

Comment: yes its json files :)

Comment: Either what you posted here does not match your actual files, or your files are not JSON. Which is it?

Comment: Please don't try to parse JSON yourself.  You have existing tools to take care of it for you.  See the JSON module on CPAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother trying to write your own JSON parser when such things already exist?

Note that what you have isn't JSON —you have extra parens around the whole and an extra comma at the end of lists— but we can compensate for those.

```
perl -MJSON::XS -CS -0777ne'
   BEGIN { $j = JSON::XS->new->relaxed(1) }
   s/^\(//;  s/\)\z//;
   CORE::say
      join ",",
         map { join ":", $_->{company}, $_->{time} }
            @{ $j->decode($_)->{Companies} }
' *.json
```

Comment: The sample input contains `},]`, which is also not valid in JSON.

Comment: i get this error : BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: @melpomene, Fixed.

Comment: @DavidBoe, That means an earlier error prevents the program from continuing. Did you perhaps get an error saying you don't have JSON::XS installed?

Comment: @ikegami same error again : BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: full error :
Can't locate JSON/XS.pm in @INC (you may need to install the JSON::XS module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: Relevant part of the error message: **you may need to install the JSON::XS module**. Alternatively, use `JSON::PP` instead of `JSON::XS`, which is a core module.

Comment: @ikegami please how include id of filename as prefix in outputs, my falenames like this : 
`file.json?a=a&b=b&c=c&d=123456` desired output `123456:COMPANY_1:20DAYS,COMPANY_2:1DAY`

Comment: @ikegami please how ignore this warning message : **malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at -e line 1.**

Comment: `join ":", $prefix, $_->{company}, $_->{time}`

Comment: End of string at position 0 means you passed an empty string (or undef?) to `->decode`, which isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use List::Util qw/pairs/;

my $str = q/"company": "COMPANY_1","time": "20DAYS","company": "COMPANY_2","time": "1DAY",/;

my @pairs = $str =~ m/"company" \s* : \s* "([^"]+)" \s* ,
                      "time" \s* : \s* "([^"]+)"/gx;
my @output;
for my $pair (pairs @pairs) {
    push @output, join(':', @$pair);
}
say join(',', @output);
```

If your original data is actually JSON that you're stripping out the `{}` and `[]`'s from for some reason, though. it's better to stick with the original data and use `JSON::XS` or whatever to parse it instead of using regular expressions.

Comment: Yes my file is JSON format, i have +1000 json file in one folder, i want get my desired output from all my json files.

Comment: @DavidBoe Then provide a sample of one of your raw JSON files.